# Android Studio crash on findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gps

I've been searching all over the Internet and just can't find solution to my problem. And the problem is that I'm not able to insert my GPS coordinates into TextView. The app crashes at this line

```
TextView latText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
```

I've set the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_gps);
```

before trying to findViewById, but it still don't work. Also I have id on that TextView so that's not the problem.

Here full code:

```
package com.example.user1.gpsgpsgps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShowGPS extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_gps);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        ShowGPS locationListener = new ShowGPS();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();

        TextView latText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
        TextView lonText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Longitude);

        latText.setText("Nothing works...");
        lonText.setText("Nothing works here either...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

And here my activity_show_gps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.markus.gps.GPSActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Latitude"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lon"
    android:id="@+id/Longitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Latitude"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/acc"
    android:id="@+id/Accuracy"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Longitude"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/alt"
    android:id="@+id/Altitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Accuracy"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/time"
    android:id="@+id/Time"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Altitude" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/refreshGPS"
    android:id="@+id/RefreshGPSButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Time"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onRefreshGPSButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I call to start the GPS (in the main):

```
public void onGPSButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowGPS.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I've been trying to get this work for nearly 6 hours now and soon I'm going to lose my mind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ShowGPS locationListener = new ShowGPS();
```

never use the new operator on a class that extends `Activity`. Using the new operator, the Activity does not go trough its lifecycle, onCreate is not called and you are not creating a View hierarchy. More important a *valid* `Context` is not attached to your `Activity`, making findViewById unusable

This line

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

should be

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

`ShowGPS` implements already `LocationListener`, you don't need to instantiate it just for the sake of the listner

Answer (score 0):

Initialized your `TextView` inside your `Oncreate` after `setContentView` and having your `textView` object as a global instance.